# How do you save an ArrayList from MainActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, save

I have an array (called arrayMain here) that I need to be saved when an item is added, and loaded when the app starts. I have researched this thoroughly, seeing solutions using things like gson and SharedPreferences, but neither work in my program. I believe these don't work because the solutions are assuming you are not putting it in the MainActivity, but instead a different class.

I am very new to programming, and am still learning. Because of this, please include EVERYTHING I will have to do (including things like importing stuff), because I do not know all of this very well. Because I don't know how a lot of my code interacts, I included almost all of it so that I don't leave anything out. Thank you for helping.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ArrayAdapter<String> mItemViewerAdapter;

public static ArrayList<String> arrayMain = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


// Get ArrayList


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceHolderFragment()).commit();
    }


    // *** POPUP field (that I left out) that returns StringMain ***
        ArrayMain.add(StringMain);

// Set ArrayList

public static class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mItemViewerAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_itemList,
                        R.id.list_item_itemList_textview,
                        arrayMain
                );

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_ItemList);
        listView.setAdapter(mItemViewerAdapter);
        return rootView;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Why don't save your `arrayMain` in database ?

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to understand the Concept of Json. How can you convert string into json and vise-versa. How to use json array and json object.
Then you find its pretty easy way to store the json "string" data in the shared preferences. Get string data from shared preferences and convert it into json Arrray or object as per your need. 
Use this data in class where you want to load data in array list.
this is not direct execution, you have to think, 
what you want to store data and how can you use stored data in your class.